# Java Developer Library

Tags: java

There is a [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/) for Objective-C.
This library include a overview of all frameworks, classes and its methods.
And I am searching for a developer library for java.
I found this [page](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-660EC670-B7DB-4005-BF2D-411E5C0B3867_cover.html), but I am not really satisfacted with it

The documentation of Oracle seems to fulfil my request, but it is not structured as the one of the iOS.

Comment: Are you looking for the official Oracle documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/

Comment: Please specify the term 'developer library' - what do you expect in such a library?

Comment: Java has Javadocs, which are easy to use documentations of each class and all its members and methods. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of the iOS Developer Library for iOs development is the [Java SE 6 Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/) from Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java SE Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/) might be a good start.